# Confusion matrix for portion of data

Tags: python, class, text-classification

I am running several machine learning models using Python and can get accuracy and confusion matrix (CM) for a given training data.
However, I am interested if there is a way to get CM for a portion of test data?

For example, if I am classifying 'cats' and 'dogs', and only want to see what 'small animals' were correctly classified?

So running model on train and checking CM just for part of test data.
Here is a rough visualisation, tried creating new df for just 'small' animals but CM is still for the whole thing.

Many thanks!

Please check image, it illustrates it better than my description!
[classification example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc6g5.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, it can easily be done. A confusion matrix is calculated from the true and predicted class for a set of instances. One can simply provides any subset of instances to the function.